# How retrieve all fields of Entity hierarchically in TWO levels depth?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

Using Dynamics 365 9.0.

I have Entity "**Opportunity**" {ID/EntityName}
**(0 -level of depth)**

It's easy to get fields.
This "**Opportunity**" relates to 3 (for example) other entities 
**(1-level depth)**

These 3 entities from level-1 have 2 (for example) relating to other entities for each entity.
**(2-level depth)**

So,  it looks like some sort of tree:

```
 Opportunity:  
     |-entity 1
     |-entity 1-1
     |-entity 1-2  
     |-entity 2
     |-entity 2-1
     |-entity 2-2  
     |-entity 3
     |-entity 3-1
     |-entity 3-2
```

How can I retrieve this structure programatically, using C#?

I tried to use `service.retrive(...)` but here I must set ID and entity name for each entity. Can this structure be retrieved in single  request?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no OOB way to do this in single SDK service call.

You have to do regressive calls for retrieving child records.

Comment: As a side note, if you have a hierarchical data set with a self-referential entity relationship - like Account / SubAccount, then you can use special FetchXML operators like "under".  The caveat is that CRM only considers relationships within the same entity as hierarchical. This article has more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/query-hierarchical-data